# Android create object and add it to the adapter of the listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a main activity and its XML file contains a ListView and a FloatingActionButton. Also I have another class, called B. When I open the activity, which is showing some of the elements in the array of B objects, I would like that when I press the FAB button, it asks me for a string, and with that string I will create a new B object. All the B object have to be listed with the ListView and the adapter. Also all the B objects have to be saved on the storage memory.

I found it difficult understand how to place the different things and how to manipulate the array of B objects to be saved on the storage. When I create a new B object, how does the adapter know that there is a new object in the array to be displayed on the screen? In which place of my activity I have to place the part of creating the B object?

FAB

```
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Allenamento a = createAllenamento();

        }
    });
```

I used AlertDialog for the input

```
public Allenamento createAllenamento(){
    Allenamento a = null;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");

// Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
    a = new Allenamento(m_Text);
    return a;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then your goal here is to notify the adapter that a new item has been added to the array list and wish to update the list view accordingly , let's say that your ArrayAdapter is called "adapter" then in order to achieve your purpose we use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

call that function after any manipulation on the arraylist

and regarding saving the arraylist to storage you should use ObjectSerializer to serialize the arraylist to be able to save it using SharedPreferences, Example :

```
  //retrieving the saved sharedPreferences if exists
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("<replace with package name>.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //editing the retrieved SharedPreferences and adding new data
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    try {

    editor.putString("key",ObjectSerializer.serialize(arraylist));

    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

   //finally we commit the editor to save changes
    editor.commit();

   //Now to retrieve the arraylist when the app is opened again
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("<replace with package name>.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   ArrayList<B> arraylist = new ArrayList<B>();

   try {

   arraylist = (ArrayList<B>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("key",ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<B>())));

   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when Allenamento is created, m_Text is still empty, and it return the empty Allenamento. Create Allenamento in the positiveButton's click listener, and add the new Allenamento to the list which you used to show the listView, then refresh the listView by using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Try this:

FAB:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createAllenamento();
        }
    });
```

And AlertDialog:

```
Allenamento a = null;
public void createAllenamento(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();
            a = new Allenamento(m_Text);
            listOfAllenamento.add(a);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```